# How to extract values using Salesforce Formula fields

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have one Text field on Custom Object as follows -

**Product_Info__c = 'DESKTOP:10,LAPTOP:20,MOUSE:20,PHONE:25' //sample value**

I want to create new formula field as DesktopCount__c which will result value as 10 in above case.

DesktopCount = 10

LAPTOPCount = 10 .. etc

Note: I can do this apex but wanted to check if its possible to do using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, use the `FIND` method coupled with an `IF` or two, and you should be on your way.

Example: (decimal) DesktopCount =

```
IF(CONTAINS(Product_Info__c,'DESKTOP:',VALUE(MID(Product_Info__c,FIND('DESKTOP:',Product_Info__c),FIND(',',Product_Info__c,FIND('DESKTOP:',Product_Info__c)))),0)
```

If the prefix text is there, grab the MID text between the prefix-text and its delimiter.

**Update**

I didn't test my function, but the basic idea is there.  I want my formula to do the following:

```
(1)  Check if the "prefix-text" is there.  
       Example: is "Desktop:" in my string?
       Available Functions:  CONTAINS()

(2)  If yes, take the text between the prefix-text and the delimiter
       Example: prefix-text="Desktop:"; delimiter=",";  result = "10"
       Available Functions:  MID(), FIND()

(3)  If there is a result, convert it to a number
       Example: 10
       Available Functions: VALUE()
```

Here's a list of [Formula Functions](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions.htm) you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer It gave me error when I used formula as follows  'IF(CONTAINS(Product_Info__c,'DESKTOP:'),VALUE(MID(Product_Info__c,FIND('DESKTOP:',Product_Info__c),FIND(',',Product_Info__c,FIND('DESKTOP:',Product_Info__c)))),0)' and value for the field was DESKTOP:10,LAPTOP:20,MOUSE:20,PHONE:25

Comment: You'll have to throw in some error checking in your formula depending on the format of the string.   And also, you'll have to play around with the formulas to get what you want.  See the Update

Comment: As a side note, formulas were not designed to do this sort of work, and one would find oneself running out of "compiled formula size characters" *very quickly*; I'd guess you'd maybe have 4-5 such formulas before you hit the limit. Use Apex Code instead, which is far better suited to this sort of work.